# Unable to run tests in Fonemonkey

Tags: automation, fonemonkey

I am facing problem with Fonemonkey. I have downloaded it from Gorillalogic.com and followed the Documentation provided with it to set up the fonemonkey with my project. However when I am running the project fonemonkey is not running.

I am new to this automation tool testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure you did all the steps in this guide?
http://www.gorillalogic.com/books/fonemonkey-doc/setup-guide/add-fonemonkey

EDIT: Especially #5 here:http://www.gorillalogic.com/books/fonemonkey/frequently-asked-questions
Is your -all_load linker flag set?